# mod_rewrite restrictions on parameter name - letter m

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite my own shortcuts to full `utm_` parameters using the following rules:

```
# rename query parameter m=>utm_medium
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?])?m=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1utm_medium=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=301]

# rename query parameter s=>utm_source
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?])?s=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1utm_source=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=301]

# rename query parameter c=>utm_campaign
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?])?c=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1utm_campaign=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=301]
```

Given the following URL:
`https://www.example.com/?m=value1&s=value2&c=value3`

The `m` parameter never gets replaced. Location of this parameter in the URL (front, middle, end) does not matter and location of the rule in `htaccess` file does not matter as well. The rule never works.

But replacing the rule for parameter `um` (also: see pre-existing `s` or `c`) works like charm on `https://www.example.com/?um=value1&s=value2&c=value3`

```
# rename query parameter um=>utm_medium
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?])?um=([^&]*)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1utm_medium=%2%3 [NC,NE,L,R=301]
```

Is there any restriction on usage of parameter `m` in mod_rewrite or am I missing something?

Comment: There's no restriction on the usage of param `m` in mod_rewrite. And your rules work as expected for me (albeit with 3 external redirects). I would guess a conflict elsewhere in `.htaccess` (order does not necessarily matter). To clarify, is the request still passed through to your application with the `m` param in place, or are you getting some other "unexpected" response? _Aside:_ `(.*[&?])?` - looks like a bit of an error? Realistically, that's the same as `(.*&)?` - unless you really are checking for a `?` in the query string itself?

Comment: Yes, the request still passed through to my application with the `m` param in place.

`[&?]` was intended for the first parameter, but maybe indeed is not necessary.

Comment: "`[&?]` was intended for the first parameter" - Yes, but this checks for `&` or `?`. You would not expect `?` here. (It looks like you are perhaps trying to make `&` _optional_, but it is already optional by the surrounding optional group.)